# gcp dataflow process element does not go to the next ParDO function

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

*I fill the map with good data (no null values) but i am not able to go next ParDo function .i tried to debug but didn't understand why is it happening .  if anyone is knows what i am doing wrong let me know .I am putting the three ParDo functions  .thanks 
*

```
.apply("Parse XML CarrierManifest ", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Manifest>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processeElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        try {

                            System.out.println(c.element());
                            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Manifest.class);
                            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                            StringReader reader = new StringReader(c.element());

                            Manifest manifest = (Manifest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

                            if (manifest == null) throw new RuntimeException("Invalid data");

                            c.output(manifest);

                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            LOG.error("Unexpected error while parsing input. File was <[ " + c.element() + " ]>", e);
                        }

                    }

                }
                )
                )

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        .apply("preparing  data  " , ParDo.of(new DoFn<Manifest,  Map<String, List<TableRow>>>()
                   {
                       @ProcessElement
                       public void processeElement(ProcessContext c)
                       {
                           Map<String, List<TableRow>> RowsTable = new ArrayMap<>();
                           RowsTable.put("Manifest",new ArrayList<>());

                           Manifest manifest = c.element();

                           Links linkss = manifest.linkes;

                           System.out.println(linkss.ShipmentsList.linakageShipment.linkageesList.size());

                           for (int i = 0; i < linkss.ShipmentsList.linakageShipment.linkageesList.size(); i++) {

                               RowsTable.get("Manifest")
                                     .add(new TableRow()
                                       .set("GROUP_ID", manifest.GroupidValue)
                                       .set("STATUS", manifest.StatusValue)
                                       .set("GROUP_TYPE", manifest.typeValue)
                                       .set("CREATED_AT", manifest.created_atValue)
                                       .set("READY_AT", manifest.ready_atValue)
                                       .set("MANIFEST_NUMBER", manifest.manifest_numberValue)
                                       .set("LINKS_SELF", linkss.SelfLink)

                                       .set("SHIPMENT_ID", linkss.ShipmentsList.linakageShipment.linkageesList.get(i).ID)
                                       .set("SHIPMENT_TYPE", linkss.ShipmentsList.linakageShipment.linkageesList.get(i).Type));
                           }
                            c.output(RowsTable);
                       }

                   }))
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               .apply("change rows list to one row ",ParDo.of(new DoFn<Map<String, List<TableRow>>, TableRow>()
               {
                   @ProcessElement
                   public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
                   {
                       System.out.println("id: " + c.element());
                       for (TableRow r : c.element().get("Manifest")) // Should only have 1
                           c.output(r);
                   }
               }))
```

Comment: For clarification, pipeline is not reaching the 3rd transform from your question, correct? In the Dataflow UI console, do you see zero output elements for the 2nd transform?

Comment: thanks vishal for your reply. it is quite strange for me because may be i am new to dataflow .  when i debug the transformations with direct runner id does'nt work after 2nd transformation , when i change my runner to DATAFLOW runner it works fine . is it normal ??

Comment: Vishal, could you please confirm the counter visually, as suggested by Andrew?

Answer (score 0):

From one of your comments in your question I understand that the issue is that your Dataflow pipeline only works when run in Dataflow itself (with the `Dataflow Runner`), but it does not work locally when you use the `Direct Runner` instead.

As explained in [the documentation for Apache Beam's Direct Runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/#additional-information-and-caveats), local execution is limited by the memory available locally, and it is recommended that the debugging process is done with small data sets that can be handled by your local machine. In any case, from that same comment I understand that you pipeline works well when executed in Dataflow, and therefore there is no issue with the Pipeline itself.

As per the description you provided, it definitely looks like the issue is related to the limitations of `Direct Runner`, but if you have more specific errors in your local/remote environment, you should be more specific in the question description and answer to the comments that request more information about your use issue in order to be able to assist you.

Comment: i tried with very small data also but the problem remains same

Comment: Can you answer the questions posted in the comments above? Also, is there any specific error message you are getting on the execution with `Direct Runner`? Can you confirm that everything works fine when executed using `Dataflow Runner`?